# Adding a scroll bar to Tkinter with a long list of data

Tags: python, tkinter, dialog, window, scrollbar

I currently have an issue with my Output in Tinker. So whenever I try to output my data read from a file the output dialog is too small to fit the huge list of data. For example:

[image: screenshot with no scrollbars]

The window is too large to display all my data so I looked into adding a scrollbar for the window in order to better fit the data and easily see all of it.

The issue arises in my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkSimpleDialog
import tkMessageBox

root = Tk()
w = Label(root, text ="my Program")
w.pack()

tkMessageBox.showinfo("Welcome", "Add your welcome message here")

with open("Logs.txt", "rb") as f_input:
    start_token = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("Serial Number", "What is the device serial number?")
    end_token = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("End Keyword", "What is the end keyword")
    reText = re.search("%s(.*?)%s" % (re.escape(start_token + ",SHOWALL"), re.escape(end_token)), f_input.read(), re.S)
    if reText:
        output = reText.group(1)
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
        scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill=Y, expand = False)

        mylist = Listbox(root, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set )
        mylist.insert(END, output)

        mylist.pack( side = LEFT, fill = Y, expand = False)
        scrollbar.config( command = mylist.yview )
        mainloop()
        # tkMessageBox.showinfo("Output", output)
        print output
    else:
        print "not found"
```

When I add the scrollbar I get his as an output:

[image: Scrollbar Error]

So what I am trying to do is fit the data in a nice window dialog that has a scrollbar.

This is the output:

```
APN=""
APU=""
APP=""
DDC=
FMT=""
HDR=
AKR=
AKT=
AKP=
PMR=
PKA=
PHN=""
PHS=""
HBI=
PMF=
PMN=
PRN=
PRF=
RET=
SFR=
SFT=
SXD=
SXV=
SXW=
SXX=
SPM=
VIT=
VID=
VPT=
ATN=
ATF=
AMT=
AMD=
LGF=
GPA=
GFN=
GFO=
GDN=
GDF=
GPN=
SCN=
SCO=
SCP=
AEE=
AET=
AES=
OUA=
BWP=
MSO=
UPE=
UPC=
UPT=
VAA=
VAR=
VAI=
IVJ=
IGM=
IGA
IGB=
IGC=
IGD=
IGE=
IGF=
VOW=
VWD=
```

Comment: Is your data all on one line?

Comment: Please show a sample of the contents of the `output` being inserted into `mylist`. It looks like you need to add newlines between the items in it (or modify your regular expression to include them in matches).

Comment: @martineau I add the contents of the OUTPUT to the original post.

Comment: Thanks for adding that to your question. My guess about needing to add newlines was wrong. In fact you need to do the opposite and remove them — one way is shown in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change how the `output` is inserted into the `Listbox`, assuming its contents is newline separated (as shown in your updated question).

The [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.insert-method) presents the `insert()` method's calling sequence as:
    **insert(index, *elements)**

So one way to do things would be to call it multiple times, once for each element, in a loop:

```
for element in output.splitlines():
    mylist.insert(END, element)
```

However, the `*` prefix on the second argument in  the documentation means that the method accepts a *variable* number of arguments starting at the point (each of which will be put on a separate line).

This means the same thing could accomplished in a single call:

```
mylist.insert(END, *output.splitlines())
```

What that does is first split the `output` data up into a list based upon the newlines in it, and then passes them as a bunch of *separate arguments* in the method call by prefixing the result returned from `output.splitlines()` with an `*`, which causes it to be "unpacked" into multiple calling arguments.

This is a fairly common Python idiom, so is worth learning and remembering. See [*Unpacking Argument Lists*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?#unpacking-argument-lists) in the documentation.

Comment: Ahh okay. That seemed to work correctly. Hopefully I can expand on my own from there. Thank you for the help. Marking this as the correct answer!